# OpenTok Windows SDK 2.16.6 Audio is not streaming

Tags: window, opentok

```
After update tokbox windows SDK from 2.14.0 to 2.16.6, my audio is not streaming... it's working when I am using 2.14.0

After downgrade to 2.14.0, it's working
After Upgrade to 2.16.6, it's not working

List the steps to reproduce the problem -> Just using 2.16.6 of windows SDK
What OS and version are you seeing this problem with -> Windows 10
What OpenTok versions were you running -> 2.16.6 of windows SDK
What session ID:- 2_MX40NjE1MDI4Mn5-MTU4NTU2ODYxMzI2OX54TlVTQlpmY0tNR2F5UDlhTnFGUEN5dmd-UH4


Inspector :- 2_MX40NjE1MDI4Mn5-
```

MTU4NTU2ODYxMzI2OX54TlVTQlpmY0tNR2F5UDlhTnFGUEN5dmd-UH4

[image]

Comment: Can you give some more details? It is reproducible with https://github.com/opentok/opentok-windows-sdk-samples/tree/master/BasicVideoChat ? Are you using any special hardware?

Comment: we just update DLL's from 2.14 to 2.16.6 and after the upgrade, audio streaming is not working.. no I am not using any special hardware.. everything working file with 2.14 
I just update dlls

Comment: can you try using NuGet package instead of updating the DLL? https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenTok.Client/